# Scala implicit def complains about return type with member defs?

Tags: scala

Defined the following implicit def meant to implement some methods required by an Akka actor event bus. The methods required are outlined in the documentation here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/scala/event-bus.html#Subchannel_Classification

```
protected implicit def subclassification: Subclassification[Classifier] = {
      def isEqual(a: Classifier, b: Classifier): Boolean = {
        a.equals(b)
      }

      def isSubclass(a: Classifier, b: Classifier): Boolean = {
        a.startsWith(b)
      }

  }
```

However, when I go to compile it I get the error: `type mismatch; found : Unit required: akka.util.Subclassification[MessageBus.this.Classifier]`

Here's what the documentation asks for specifically:

> `subclassification: Subclassification[Classifier]` is an object
>   providing isEqual(a: Classifier, b: Classifier) and isSubclass(a:
>   Classifier, b: Classifier) to be consumed by the other methods of this
>   classifier.

I'm aware that this would return a unit, but how would I make the implementations necessary that could also provide those member methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mean to instantiate a subclass of `Subclassification[Classifier]`?  If so, you need to say `new Subclassification[Classifier]` so that Scala knows that what's you're trying to do.

```
protected implicit def subclassification: Subclassification[Classifier] = 
  new Subclassification[Classifier] {
    def isEqual(a: Classifier, b: Classifier): Boolean = {
      a.equals(b)
    }

    def isSubclass(a: Classifier, b: Classifier): Boolean = {
      a.startsWith(b)
    }
}
```

The reason it complains is because you are assigning to the variable `subclassification` a block of code that contains only two function declarations.  Since Scala always assumes the last expression in the block to be what the expression evaluates to, and the type of a function declaration is `Unit` (basically meaning that it doesn't evaluate to anything), Scala says that the entire block has type `Unit`.

Since you are assigning the block to the variable `subclassification`, `subclassification` must be of type `Unit`.  But you explicitly state that the type should be `Subclassification[Classifier]`, so there is a mismatch, and you get an error.

Comment: Apparently so, definitely a misunderstanding on my part. Thanks. I will also note it needs `import akka.util.Subclassification` for future searchers ;)